# How can we notify the admin about newly added project by user, by default project is_active=False

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, notifications

How the admin will be notified on the dashboard (not by mail), and verify all the projects or can decline the projects.

```
class Compaigns(models.Model):
    nameOfDeceased = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    nameOfDeceasedEn = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    projectName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    projectNameEn = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/compaigns/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
    is_compaign = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    **is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)**
    detail = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    detailEn = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    suggestedDonation = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, default=0.000)
    compaignCategory = models.ManyToManyField(CompaignCategory)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nameOfDeceased

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Compaigns"
```

Comment: could use signals for the notification process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by:

1. Overriding  `models.Model`'s [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) method
2. Using [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#post-save) signal

by overriding **save()** method:

```py
class Compaigns(models.Model):
    # ... Your model's fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nameOfDeceased

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Compaigns"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
        send_notification() # your method to send notification to admin
```

Using **signal** is a little more complicated than overriding save() method. For further reading I added django docs link.